# How to load sfPropelPager from sfPropelORMPlugin?

Tags: plugins, symfony1, propel, autoload, pager

symfony already has sfPropelPager and it seems to take precedence of one from plugin.
And it is incompatible with plugin ORM thus causing nasty errors in SQL.
What's the right way to change autoload to fix this problem?

```
<?php
require_once '/usr/share/php/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';

sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
    public function setup()
    {
        $this->enableAllPluginsExcept(array('sfDoctrinePlugin', 'sfPropelPlugin'));
        $this->enablePlugins(array('sfPropelORMPlugin'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable the plain old **sfPropelPlugin**:

```
<?php
// config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    // http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfProjectConfiguration#method_disableplugins
    $this->disablePlugins('sfPropelPlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfPropelORMPlugin');
  }
}
```

Comment: No. As you can see your code is pretty much like the one I had. I also found ProjectConfiguration class in sfPropelORMPlugin. There are $this->setPluginPath('sfPropelORMPlugin', ...), sfConfig::set('sf_propel_path', ...). Should it execute automatically or I should call it somehow? Maybe copy-paste to my setup().